# How to convert a long list of strings to a comma seperated array in vi editor?

Tags: vi

Say I have a list of 300 words:

```
foo
bar
..
..
zzz
```

I want to

1. Add quotes around them like -> foo becomes "foo"
2. Generate  a comma seperated list.

E.G: ["foo", "bar", .., "zzz"]

in vi editor. How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: must you do this in vi?  very simple to accomplish with bash.

Comment: how to do it in bash

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash implementation... I think that there might be a way to run scripts in vi but I don't know why anyone would do that.

```
#/bin/bash
inputFile=path/to/your/file.txt

str=

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do   
   str=$str\"$line\",; 
done < $inputFile.txt

echo [ ${str%?} ] > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume every line of the file contains exactly one word.

Then a sequence of vi commands like this will accomplish the task:

```
:%s/.*/"&"/
^G1G300J:s/" "/","/g
I[^[A]^[
```

- `%s/.*/"&"/` does a search and replace on every line, wrapping in quotes (type RETURN to execute)
- `^G` is CTRL-G - note of the number of lines (we'll assume it shows 300)
- `1G` moves to first line
- `300J` joins the next 300 lines together with spaces
- `:s/" "/","/g` replaces space between quoted words with commas (type RETURN to execute)
- `I[` prepends bracket to start of line. `^[` is ESC to finish entry
- `A]` appends bracket to end of line. `^[` is ESC to finish entry
- Done!

As an alternative, I've started to quite like `jq`. Performing this particular task from the shell commandline becomes simply:

```
jq <wordlist -Rc '[inputs]'
```

or called from within vi, operating directly on a wordlist being edited:

```
1G!Gjq -Rc '[inputs]'
```